# custom radio box with letter inside

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a true problem here, i need style this input radio like this form below:
where P, M, G and GG are my radio buttons, can anyone help to do this only with CSS?
[image]

Comment: `Only CSS` so why is this tagged `javascript`?

Comment: Is it ok for you to have a solution with JQuery?

Comment: @RUJordan is a plan 'B' hehe =p

Comment: @LeandroRuel are you open to accept answers with JQuery solution?

Comment: @LeandroRuel check my answer.I created a pure javascript solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a similar way to Blake Mann's, but without requiring absolutely positioned elements and other "hacks". You can just use the `<label>` tag to get the same effect:

HTML:

```
<form action="#">
    <label class="coolbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="P" value="P"/>
        <span>P</span>
    </label>
    <label class="coolbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="M" value="M"/>
        <span>M</span>
    </label>
    <label class="coolbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="G" value="GG"/>
        <span>G</span>
    </label>
    <label class="coolbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="GG" value="GG"/>
        <span>GG</span>
    </label>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
label.coolbox {
    background:#546;
    padding:10px;
    margin:2px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:35px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
}
label.coolbox input {display:none;}
label.coolbox span {color:white;}
label.coolbox input:checked + span {color:#9F9;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4e3TY/)**

[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4e3TY/1/) shows another way to do it, using the `for=""` attribute, to refer to the id of the input you want to trigger with the `<label>`.

#### Using a background-image

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4e3TY/3/)** is a demo that shows how you can do this with background-images. I've used the second demo's layout, with the `for` attribute, because that is generally easier to work with in my opinion. This demo instead uses the following:

```
label.coolbox {
    margin:2px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:47px;
    height:36px;
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/BD2XGdN.png");
    background-position:top;
}
input:checked + label.coolbox {
    background-position:bottom;
}
```

What happens now is it switches between `background-position`. `top` means that the top half is shown, `bottom` means the bottom half is shown. This is because I made the `width` and `height` exactly the same as one of the two halves of that image. If you'd modify either the width or the height, the background image wouldn't look as good.

You can also try:

- [with letters inside the boxes](http://jsfiddle.net/4e3TY/4/)
- [using radio boxes instead](http://jsfiddle.net/4e3TY/5/)

If you change the `name` attribute in any of the demos, so that they are the same in all inputs, and then change the `type` attribute to `radio`, you'll have the same effect as the radio boxes demo.

Comment: cool, but, i'm trying do it using a png image, to checked and not checked. http://i.imgur.com/BD2XGdN.png

Comment: You can do that too, just use a background-image on the label instead. I'll make a demo of how that'd work.

Comment: @LeandroRuel I've added a working demo with that image. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

### [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5svAp/)

In the above fiddle just replace the image in the javascript `http://javabooksync.netai.net/Projects/m.png` with the cross image you want.

### [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5svAp/7/)

In the above fiddle all labels use same background-image `http://i.imgur.com/BD2XGdN.png`

Comment: and about the letters inside? "P", "M", "G", "GG"

Comment: The background-image behind letter, is the same of the checkbox above on the image, so, when checked, appear a "X" on it

Comment: What is that actually.I dont understand the language in the image.Tell me what this "P" , "M" , "G" , "GG" is used for

Comment: is only the size of a tshirt, in europe, as: X XL XXL

Comment: So you want it to appear on gender selection or want it already be present on page load.Also are they clickable?

Comment: already be present. in the form, this is a reprint form, when no have more tshirts. and this send a e-mail when avaliable.

Comment: hm...the radio buttons are the letters P, M, G and GG. at fiddle are "span", must be like the Blake answer, using this png: http://i.imgur.com/BD2XGdN.png

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with pure CSS, though it won't support IE8 or below:

You just need to set the `opacity` of the input elements to `0`, and position them absolutely within a container element. Then you can use the `:checked` pseudo-selector to style other elements inside that container for only the checked input.

See example:

http://jsfiddle.net/S69Dx/

Note that I placed the letters within a `span` element, and then selected that with `input:checked + span`. The span next to the checked input.

Comment: is possible change the background-image of radio using this png? http://i.imgur.com/BD2XGdN.png

Comment: Sure, just make that span the width and height you want (or you might want to make that a div instead) and then style it with the background instead of putting the background on the container div like I did. Then you can style that div however you want using that `:checked` selector

Comment: i think is possible using :not(:checked) too, to not checked, and :checked to checked, right?

Comment: Yes, but it might be less work to just assign your 'not checked' styles to the input by default, and then apply your 'checked' styles with the special selector. It would also help if you need to work on fallbacks for older browsers